# Kernel module doesn't call probe function

Tags: kernel, i2c

I'm writing a kernel modul which should work on i2c.

The problem is:
the `probe` function doesn't load automatically. AFAIK, it should be called with a correct device driver name. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So my question is:
what is the right device driver name for the i2c modul on Raspberry Pi?

As an example I have found this: http://home.hiwaay.net/~jeffj1/i2c-bcm2708.c
and tried a lot, like bcm2708_i2c, i2c, i2c_dev

My code look like this:

```
#define DRV_NAME    "bcm2708_i2c"

static struct platform_driver bcm2708_i2c_driver = {
    .driver     = {
        .name   = DRV_NAME,
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe      = bcm2708_i2c_probe,
    .remove     = __devexit_p(bcm2708_i2c_remove),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several modules associated with I2C on the Pi.

I guess you want i2c_bcm2708

```
lsmod | grep i2c
regmap_i2c              1661  3 snd_soc_pcm512x,snd_soc_wm8804,snd_soc_core
i2c_bcm2708             4943  0 
i2c_dev
```